# Updating a page from another page whats the best and easy way?

Tags: javascript, php

So my problem is if there are 2 pages for example. `PricePage.html` has the list of prices and `UpdatePrice.html` has the input text and etc. If I use the `UpdatePrice.html` to change the prices of `PricePage.html`, whats the best way should I use? via `php` to `php` or via `php` to `mysql` or theres even an easier way to do it. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What you have to do is, whenever there is an update in price, submit that data to your server. If your backend is in php and database is mysql, the form is submitted to an endpoint of your choice. Handle that request in php. Basically, get the data. Connect to your mysql database and save the data. Pricepage can then retrieve that data from mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of it as updating one page from another.  Think of it as two separate pages that both interact with a database.

- Store your price information in a database (such as MySQL).
- Have `PricePage` query the database to get the price information, and generate the HTML to display it.  (This means the page can't be just static HTML; it needs to use something like PHP that can generate HTML dynamically.)
- Have the `UpdatePrice` page store the new price information in the database.  (This doesn't *directly* modify `PricePage`, but next time someone views that page, it'll retrieve and display the latest information in the database.)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to get updated in real time like once the data is updated it gets reflected on other page,then you can use sockets which will listen for the update event and once the event is fired the contents will get updated.

One of the most popular framework for this business is [socket.io](https://socket.io/).
I would suggest you to have a look to it.The benefit for using this approach is that you save a lot of resource and the functions work in realtime.